# How to stop a python program for a certain amount of time?

Tags: python, multithreading, time, delay

I would like to know how to stop a python program after a certain amount of time. I am aware to the `time.sleep(sec)` method from the `time` module, but that method delays only the current thread. I would like to delay the entire program. Is there a way I could do this?

Please tell me if you need a use case.

Comment: https://stackabuse.com/python-make-time-delay-sleep-for-code-execution

Maybe the async part of the article can help you

Comment: I read the article and I don't really understand how it would help in my scenario. It doesn't provide a way to do what I need to do.